# What does the curve branch for $\omega > \omega_p$ mean for surface plasmon dispersion?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, condensed-matter, dielectric, dispersion

Consider a half-infinite metal (the other half is vacuum with $\varepsilon=1$).
By solving Maxwell's equations and using boundary conditions at the interface, we get the dispersion:

$$ \frac{\varepsilon_1}{k_{z1}} + \frac{\varepsilon_2}{k_{z2}} = 0$$
where  $$k_{zi}^2=\varepsilon_i (\frac{\omega}{c})^2 - {k_x}^2$$

$$\varepsilon_1=1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2},\,\, \varepsilon_2=1$$
So (1) is metal modelled by Drude model, and (2) is vacuum.
(take $c,\omega_p=1$)

What does the dispersion curve for $\omega\ge\omega_p$ mean? In the plot below it tends to $w=\sqrt{2}k$ (red line). Does that mean it travels through the bulk as if $\varepsilon_i=1/\sqrt{2}$? What is the physical significance of its gradient tending to $\sqrt{2}$ rather than $1$?

[image: plot dispersion for half-infinite metal]

(Ref: Heinz Raether, Surface Plasmons on Smooth and Rough Surfaces and on Gratings p~5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the second mode of the plasma, with a different energy-momentum relation. If one can match momentum and energy properly, this mode may be excited like the first one. The best way to understand the difference will be to simulate the fields and watch them directly.